# iPhone 7 Plus stuck at Recovery Mode after downgrading from iOS 11

Tags: ios, itunes, beta

Understand that some people managed to resolve the "stuck at Recovery Mode" by installing back the iOS 11.

- [iPhone 7 Plus stuck in recovery mode and can't restore/update even in DFU](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/287747/iphone-7-plus-stuck-in-recovery-mode-and-cant-restore-update-even-in-dfu)

Would someone walk me through the steps in some detail the process of how to do this?

Comment: I’ll try to get something better than https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/260999/whats-the-difference-between-dfu-and-recovery-mode-restore-if-i-dont-downgrade? in the morning.

Comment: you should try this https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203282?cid=tw_sr I got it from Apple Support

Comment: You just need to use iOS 10.3.3 beta ipsw to restore

Answer (score 3):

Solved it with the following steps

- Manually download the IPSW file corresponding to your iPhone model via the links found on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSBeta/comments/6jmgl3/official_apple_ios_11_developer_beta_2_update_1/).
- Connect iPhone to Mac/PC
- In iTunes, select the phone and click on "Upgrade" with either <kbd>Opt/Alt</kbd> (Mac) or <kbd>Shift</kbd> (PC) pressed, then select the IPSW file you've just downloaded
- Installation will start and you will be back at iOS 11.

Comment: CAUTION - today the reddit links look like legitimate apple download links. I prefer to get the downloads from Apple's web site directly - so use caution when downloading software - even beta software to be sure it's legitimate and properly signed/unadulterated.